# What does leal (%eax, %eax) do?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

What does `leal (%eax, %eax)` do? Does that multiply the contents at %eax * 2 since it has parens?

Comment: Isn't there an operand missing?

Comment: Right hirschhomsalz, that's not how it's commonly called, so most examples don't cover this use of it, only the three operand version.

So I'm not sure if you're the one that gave me a -1, but I think it's a legit question if you yourself didn't realize that it works this way (because I didn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will load the destination operand with the sum of `eax` and `eax`, IOW, 2*`eax`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this was hard for me to find this specific use of it, so hopefully this will help those who also face this in the future.